# Ruby on Rails - Make view accessible to certain users

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, controller, user-permissions

In my application I have models `File` & `FileAccess`. *User A* can upload files and give access to many other users *(by other users asking for access)*.

*My Models:*

```
class File < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :file_accesses

class FileAccess < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :file
```

*My `FilesController`:*

```
class FilesController < ApplicationController
  def accepted_users
     FileAccess.create(user_id: params[:user_id], file_id: params[:file_id], accept: true)
  end
```

*My `routes.rb`:*

```
get 'i/:user_id/:file_id', to: 'files#accepted_users', as: :file_access_accepted
```

*My View:*

```
= link_to "Give Access", file_access_accepted_path(@file, other_user.id)
```

*Other users* can ask for access & *user A* can select users that they want to give file access to by clicking on *Give Access* button.

In my `FilesController` I have a `access_file` action & view:

```
class FilesController < ApplicationController
  def access_file
    redirect_to @file, alert: "You don't have access to this page!" if @file.user != current_user
  end
```

Currently this view/page is only viewable to *File owner* and if user is not the file owner, they'll be send back with a alert.

How can I achieve it so this page/view is accessible to *File owner* **AND** all other users that have been accepted `accept: true` by the *file owner*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
def access_file
  if @file.user != current_user && !@file.file_accesses.map(&:user).include?(current_user)
    redirect_to @file, alert: "You don't have access to this page!"
  end
end
```

or

```
def access_file
  if @file.user != current_user && !FileAccess.exists?(file: @file, user: current_user)
    redirect_to @file, alert: "You don't have access to this page!"
  end
end
```

The latter should be just one SQL query

Comment: Thanks a bunch @Ursus. Appreciate you tok your time :)

Comment: Yeah worked fine. I just added a small twick to it for my use :)